# Java Regex match between string and a space

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string in Java.

`ActivityRecord{7615a77 u0 com.example.grano.example_project/.MainActivity t20}`

My need is to get the string `MainActivity`, ie the part between the `./` and the space after the word.

So basically I'm looking for a regular expression able to catch something in the middle of given characters and a white space.

Comment: And I need £1,000,000. [Have you tried anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the expression:

```
(?<=\/\.)\w+?(?=\s)
```

Broken down:

```
(?<=  \/\.  )
 ^ lookbehind
       ^ for a literal / followed by a literal .

\w  +?
 ^ word character
    ^ one or more (non-greedy)

(?=  \s  )
 ^ lookahead
     ^ a whitespace character
```

[Test it here](https://regex101.com/r/8gyAyU/2).

Comment: It is worth noticing that we don't need to escape `/` in Java's regex since it doesn't use `/regex/flags` syntax which means `/` is not special character.

Comment: @Pshemo Didn't know that. Thanks. I'll keep it the same though because Regex101 doesn't support that.

Comment: Thanks, really nice and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your proceeding text doesn't have / in it and the text you want to isolate doesn't have a space in it, you can use this

```
replaceAll("^[^/]*/\\.([^ ]*).*$","$1"));
```

which looks from the start for the first /, then /., then captures everything up to the first space from that point, and then matches everything else, and replaces it all with the capture

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this [**`/\.(.*?)\s`**](https://regex101.com/r/Cwf4zl/1) with pattern like :

```
String str = ...;
String regex = "/\\.(.*?)\\s";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    //-------------------------------^-----get the group (.*?) between '/.' and 'space'
}
```

**Output**

```
MainActivity
```